# Does a nested enum inside POD class makes it not POD?

Tags: c++, enums, nested

By definition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c), *POD* is a simple class with no user-defined constructors, non static members, and containing simple data types only.

The question is, will these 2 classes below be equivalent as *POD* types (in terms of memory footprint):

```
class pod
{
public:
   int x;
   double y;
};

class pod1
{
public:
   int x;
   double y;

   enum POD_TYPE
   {
      POD1 = 0,
      POD = 1
   };
};
```

In other words does adding *enum* to the class only affects scope resolution of *enum* and does not affect properties of the class itself? By observation, it seems that class is still pod, but I would like to confirm based on the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that type is still POD. The definition is given by C++11 9/10:

> A POD struct is a non-union class that is both a trivial class and a standard-layout class, and has no non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types).

*Trivial* means that it doesn't do any funny business when creating, destroying or copying objects. *Standard-layout* means that it doesn't do any funny business with the layout of data members: no polymorphism, and restrictions on what you can do with access specifiers and inheritance. These terms are fully defined in C++11 9/6 and 9/7, if you want more detail.

Nested types (such as your enumeration), static data members and non-virtual member functions (apart from constructors etc. which would make it non-trivial) will not effect any of those things, so it is still POD.

**UPDATE:** Since you say you're interested in historic definitions, C++03 defined:

> 9/4 A POD-struct is an aggregate class that has no non-static members of type non-POD-struct, non-POD-union (or array of such types), and has no user-defined copy assignment operator and no user-defined destructor"
>
> 8.5.1/1 An aggregate is an array or class with no user-declared constructors, no private or protected non-static data members, no base classes and no virtual functions.

So there were more restrictions; but nested types were still allowed. I don't have a copy of C++98, but I'm sure that would be identical to C++03.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very comprehensive summary! You mention C++11, which relaxes the conditions for POD - would your answer be still applicable for regular C++ (part regarding nested types)?

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy: The short answer is yes. I've updated my answer to include historic definitions.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make any difference regarding POD status because defining a nested `enum` does not add data members to the class. In fact, you could also define a nested class that is *not* POD inside `pod1` and it would still not make a difference regarding the PODness of `pod1`.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought too! But, does the standard explicitly states that (for regular C++, for C++11 it does by @Mike Seymour answer), or it is just common thing for most compiler implementations?

Answer (score 1):

The *enum* `POD_TYPE` is a *type* and won't effect the *layout*, we can see this from the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `9.2` *Class members* paragraph *1* which says:

> [...]Members of a class are data members, member functions (9.3), nested types, and
>   enumerators. Data members and member functions are static or non-static; see 9.4. **Nested types are classes (9.1, 9.7) and enumerations (7.2)** [...]

as opposed to *data members* and we can further see that the definition of a  *standard layout class* depends only on data member from paragraph *16* which says:

> Two standard-layout struct (Clause 9) types are layout-compatible if they have the same number of non-static data members and corresponding non-static data members (in declaration order) have layout-compatible types (3.9).

and we further see going back to section `9` *Classes* paragraph *10* which says(*emphasis mine*):

> A POD struct<sup>108</sup> is a non-union class that is **both a trivial class and a standard-layout class**, and has **no non-static data members** of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types). Similarly, a POD union is a union that is both a trivial class and a standard layout class, and has no non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types). A POD class is a class that is either a POD struct or a POD union.

As far as I can tell the *pre C++11* standard does not diff much in the above items.